# How to autofill a second column based on first column selection in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have two columns **User name** and **ID** in **sheet 1** in my google sheet. In **sheet 2** I have a list of all the user names and their corresponding ID's.

I have created a drop down list for column **User name** in **sheet 1** with values picking from the user names column range in sheet 2. The challenge is, how do I make it such that whenever I pick a user name from the drop down list in **sheet 1** for **User name** column, It automatically fills the column **ID** with the matching ID value from sheet 2

Comment: There too many ways. Vlookup, index/match, filter, query all these function will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where `targetCol` is the column that contains what you want to return, and `matchCol` is the column with the ID to search for and `dropdown` is the dropdown cell:

```
INDEX(sheet2!targetCol, MATCH(dropdown, sheet2!matchCol, 0))
```

You can use VLOOKUP, but I prefer INDEX/MATCH.  To use VLOOKUP, the data on Sheet2 must be set up with the search column on the left of the return column.  Then you would do something like this:

```
VLOOKUP(dropdown, Sheet2!matchCol:targetCol, index)
```

where index is the number of the column with reference to the data range passed (Sheet2!matchCol:targetCol), and can either be manually determined (eg.: 5 for the 5th column over) or calculated (ie.: targetCol-matchCol+1).

Answer (score 0):

use in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; Sheet2!A:B; 2; )))
```